# CKEditor Link dialog modification

Tags: modal-dialog, ckeditor

I am trying to add a drop down to CKEditor's link dialog. When selected, the drop down should insert corresponding class name to the link.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' );

    infoTab.add({
      type: 'select',
      label: 'Display link as a button',
      id: 'buttonType',
      'default': '',
      items: [
        ['- Not button -', ''],
        ['Button one', 'btn-primary'],
        ['Button two', 'btn-success'],
        ['Button three', 'btn-danger']
      ],

      commit: function(data) {
        data.className = this.getValue();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I have a feeling commit function is not doing the job, but cannot figure out how to make it work. I saw a code that almost does the same thing as I want at http://www.lxg.de/code/simplify-ckeditors-link-dialog. I tried it and it does not work either.

I am using CKEditor 4.3.2.

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `console.log` the `data` object in link dialog's `onOk`, you'll find quite a different hierarchy. Element classes are in `data.advanced.advCSSClasses`. But even if you decide to override (or extend) the value of this property in your `commit`, your string will be nuked by the original `commit` of `advCSSClasses` input field  ("Advanced" tab) anyway. So the approach got to be a little bit different:

1. Always store the value of the select in `data`.
2. Override `commit` of `advCSSClasses` input field to consider stored value.
3. Remember to execute the original `commit` of `advCSSClasses` input.

Here we go:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if ( dialogName == 'link' ) {
    var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'info' ),
        advTab =  dialogDefinition.getContents( 'advanced' ),
        advCSSClasses = advTab.get( 'advCSSClasses' );

    infoTab.add( {
      type: 'select',
      label: 'Display link as a button',
      id: 'buttonType',
      'default': '',
      items: [
        ['- Not button -', ''],
        ['Button one', 'btn-primary'],
        ['Button two', 'btn-success'],
        ['Button three', 'btn-danger']
      ],

      commit: function( data ) {
        data.buttonType = this.getValue();
      }
    });

    var orgAdvCSSClassesCommit = advCSSClasses.commit;
    advCSSClasses.commit = function( data ) {
        orgAdvCSSClassesCommit.apply( this, arguments );

        if ( data.buttonType && data.advanced.advCSSClasses.indexOf( data.buttonType ) == -1 )
            data.advanced.advCSSClasses += ' ' + data.buttonType;
    };
  }
});
```

Now you got to only write a `setup` function which will detect whether one of your button classes is present to set a proper value of your select field once the dialog is open.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @oleq. When I `console.log(data)` in the `commit` function, I only get `Object {type: "url"}` and data.advanced is not defined. It seems `data` is not a fully constructed object when passed to `commit`.

Comment: @KiKim Updated my answer. You're right, "Advanced" tab commits its data after "Info" tab.

Comment: While `data` object was pretty much empty inside `commit`, it was full object inside `advCSSClasses.commit`. The reason it still did not work was `data` did not have `advanced` property, but it did have `adv`. After fixing that, it worked like a charm (I also updated your code). Thank you very much oleq.

Comment: My change `data.advanced` to `data.adv` in your code did not stick around. I guess only you can update it. When you get a chance, would you kindly update it for the sake of completeness and future reference? Thanks.

Comment: @KiKim Since CKEditor 4.4.0 and [#11341](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11341) `data.advanced` is used instead of `data.adv` ([the commit](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/e5f68976d2)). Thus the proposed change is invalid.